# How can I cast the return from Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "HH"); to an integer?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, casting

I have tried a million ways with no luck. I know I could use a date object and getHours method but I need it to be EST timezone specific.

```js
function test () { 
   var hour = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "HH");
   Logger.log(hour);
   var hourtest = +hour;
   Logger.log(hourtest);
   hourtest = parseInt(hour);
   Logger.log(hourtest);
   hourtest = Number(hour);
}
```

Logs return:

```
[19-11-13 20:48:04:213 CST] 21
[19-11-13 20:48:04:214 CST] 21.0
[19-11-13 20:48:04:214 CST] 21.0
```

I need to be able to take the hour return as an integer and add or subtract from it and compare to other integer values
I have tried something like if(hours == 21) {var test = true} and when logging test it wasn't true.

Please help.

Comment: You're doing it the correct way. I suspect `Logger.log()` is converting the int to a float.

Comment: What happens if you do `Logger.log(21)`?

Comment: *have tried something like if(hours == 21) {var test = true} and when logging test it wasn't true.* Could you provide this code instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a type issue as long as you're using the abstract comparison `==`. Consider the following example:

```
function f21() {
  var list21 = ["21", 21, 21.0]
  for (var i=0; i < list21.length; i++) {
    Logger.log( list21[i] == 21 )
  }
}
/** Outputs to:
[19-11-14 10:12:42:816 EET] true
[19-11-14 10:12:42:816 EET] true
[19-11-14 10:12:42:817 EET] true
*/
```

`parseInt` works great for converting to an integer but integers are usually displayed as a float by Logger.